# AD Graph API: extending session-cookies or token-max-age time

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

From https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/4025960/federated-users-in-azure-ad-are-forced-to-sign-in-frequently

> Federated users who do not have the LastPasswordChangeTimestamp
>   attribute synced are issued session cookies and refresh tokens that
>   have a Max Age value of 12 hours.

the link shared above seems to point out to do it via powershell, but it seems the given command has no effect (updating `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp`)

I wonder:

- Is there a way extend token-max-age / session-cookies above 12 hours via graph api?
- Is there a way to sync `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` via GraphApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD Graph API doesn't support to change the token-max-age / session-cookies. And it also doesn't support to sync `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp`. More detail about Azure AD Graph, you can refer [Entity and complex type reference | Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

If you have any idea or feedback about Azure AD Graph, you can submit it from [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/165567-graph-api).

In-addition, I am also failed update the `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` using the PowerShell, you may use the AAD Connect solution mentioned from that document.

Answer (score 1):

We are having the same problem and cannot set the attribute `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` with powershell. The Azure Support said that setting this property is not supported anymore due to internal design changes and suggested us to go for https://feedback.azure.com to provide a design change request.

You can find the request here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/30930691-possibility-to-set-attribute-lastpasswordchangetim

Comment: I also voted this one : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/20597512-make-it-possible-to-update-lastpasswordchangetimes (maybe also useful for you)